# next button not highlighting or displaying matches

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The jquery highlight that I have created works well, but for some reason when I type something in the input field and hit the next button it doesn't highlight the terms. It only displays "1 of 0 mathches". I'm not sure why it won't highlight it.

Below is my script:

```
<script>
$("[data-search=next]").click(function() {
    if (variableCounter < totalCount) variableCounter = variableCounter + 1;
    else variableCounter = 1;

    $(".kwt-count").html(variableCounter + " of " + totalCount + " Matches");
  });
</script>
```

Also when the term is in the field and I hit the enter key it highlights the verbiage, but when I hit the delete key it unmarks the content, but the full string is removed along with the highlight. I want it to remove "all" highlights on delete or backspace key, but not remove the full string from the input field. Not sure why its removing everything in the input field.

```
<script>
  $input.keydown("input", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 46 || e.keyCode === 8) {
      $content.unmark();
      $input.val(" ").focus();
    }
  });
</script>
```

I have created a codepen of my code here: https://codepen.io/dude12go8/pen/PoYbdXd

Comment: I don't think you need to bind conditional key codes to the search field. If you delete the condition on line 126, it works normally.

Comment: Reason why I have it binding so it removes the highlight on delete key, but i want it to remove the highlight, but not removed the full string in the input field

Comment: I figured it out. I removed `$input.val(" ").focus();` but not there is a lag when the backspace key is hit. Any idea how to get rid of the lag?